# How can i get the album art from MediaStore?

Tags: android

How can I get the album art from MediaStore? I try something like:

```
String[] projectionImages  = new  String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART, MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_KEY};


Cursor c = contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projectionImages, null, null, null);

if(c != null){
      c.moveToFirst();
      Log.e(TAG, "am gasit " + c.getString(0) + " " + c.getString(1));
  }
 else{
      Log.e(TAG, "No image");
 }
```

but is not working.. I retrive just null for every entry!

Thank you!

Comment: Was this helpful at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it iterate over the amount of entries you see in the directory or do the numbers not match up?

The following works for me when searching for images in teh MediaStore

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
do {
    int col = cursor.getColumnIndex(Images.Media.DESCRIPTION);
    String description = cursor.getString(col);
    if (new Long(item).toString().equals(description)) {
        imageId = cursor.getPosition();
        int dataColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(Images.Media.DATA);
        filePath = cursor.getString(dataColumn);
        return true;
    }
} while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

Comment: imageId = cursor.getPosition(); doesn't seem to bed used anywhere in the snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
Cursor cursorAlbum = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART},MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID+ "=" + album_id, null, null);

    if(cursorAlbum != null  && cursorAlbum.moveToFirst())
      {

        String uri = cursorAlbum.getString(cursorAlbum.getColumnIndex("album_art"));
        cursorAlbum.close();
        if(uri != null )    image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(uri));

      }
```

Comment: album_id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID)).   this will give you the albumId of the current item that the cursor is pointing to. Hope this helps :)

Comment: How can i use it as a bitmap??

Comment: you can use this 
    Bitmap bitmap =MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);